# 2 AJAX calls in the same view (CakePHP 2.3)

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I have problem with AJAX in CakePHP. I have 2 different AJAX forms in one view. The first AJAX form works well, but the other one doesn't work properly. When I call the second AJAX, it doesn't set data from this form to `$this->request->data`, but the AJAX will run properly. After that, it will update `<div id="about"></div>`. Curious is fact, that after the div is updated and I try send data through this form again, it works and it will update my data in database. Also when I have only the second AJAX in the view, it will work properly and send the data first time I send the data through it.

Here's my code:

This is a view file:

```
<div id="price-list">
    <?php echo $user['User']['price_list']; ?>
</div>

<?php
    echo $this->Form->create('User');
    echo $this->Form->input('User.price_list', array('label' => false));
    echo $this->Js->submit('Save', array(
        'url' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'ajax_edit_price_list'),
        'update' => '#price-list',
        'buffer' => false,
    ));
?>

<div id="about">
    <?php echo $user['User']['about']; ?>
</div>

<?php
    echo $this->Form->create('User');
    echo $this->Form->input('User.about', array('label' => false));
    echo $this->Js->submit('Save', array(
        'url' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'ajax_edit_about'),
        'update' => '#about',
        'buffer' => false,
    ));
?>
```

I have also append `<?php echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(); ?>` in my default.ctp before `</body>`.

Do you have any idea, where can be a problem? Thanks

Comment: Can you add the relevant parts of the generated HTML? Most importantly the JavaScript that is generated by CakePHP? I suspect CakePhp gets confused because both forms are generated for the same 'model' and may get the same 'id'. To fix this, you can specify an id manually inside Form->create(), although I'm not sure that the generated Ajax JavaScript will pick that up automatically. It's, of course, always an option to hand-code the JavaScript which will give you greater control as well

Comment: thank you very much for your reply :) the problem was as @AdamTaylor wrote, that I havent attached $this->Form->end(); at the end of each form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to reproduce your exact issue, but I think I know the problem. Your second form is being created inside of the first form. You need to add `echo $this->Form->end();` to the end of both forms.

Also, the forms are getting created with the same ID. Although this isn't what's causing the problem, it's still not good. I suggest you take thaJeztah's advice and specify an ID manually inside `$this->Form->create()`.

Comment: Thank you very much, you were right. Now it works perfect. I thought that $this->Js->submit() will do the work instead of $this->Form->end()...Thanks again :)

Comment: @Johny You're welcome! I'm glad your problem has been resolved.

Comment: @AdamTaylor well spotted, I overlooked the missing Form->end()