# Making Ajax Calls in CakePHP

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I am trying to make an Ajax call in CakePHP. The first call is working fine and it renders a view with another Ajax submit button. The code below is in first view:

```
echo $this->Js->submit('LOAD COMMENTS',array(
                'url'=>array(
                    'controller'=>'Nominees',
                    'action'=>'load_comments'
                    ),
                'before'=>$this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeIn'),
                'success'=>$this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeOut'),
                'update'=>'#comments'
                ));
echo $this->Form->end();
```

In the Nominees controller i have

```
public $components = array('RequestHandler');
/*Load comments for the nominee using ajax*/
public function load_comments(){

    if(!empty($this->request->data)){

        /* Demoting Irrelevant comments.
Only triggered if the demote comment button is clicked.*/
        if(isset($this->request->data['Nominee']['comment_nominee_id'])){
            $comment_id = $this->request->data['Nominee']['comment_nominee_id'];
            $this->Nominee->updateAll(
            array('Nominee.status' =>0),
            array('Nominee.id'=>$comment_id));
        }

        $userNumber = $this->request->data['Nominee']['number'];
        $award_id = $this->request->data['Nominee']['award'];
        $dt = date('Y');
        $nominationInfor = $this->Nominee->find('all',array(
                            'conditions' => array('Nominee.reg_number'=>$studNumber,'Nominee.year'=>$dt,'Nominee.award_id'=>$award_id,'Nominee.status'=>1),
                            'recursive' => -1
                            ));
        if(empty($nominationInfor)){
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('No Nomination Information Available.'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'choose_category'));
        }
        $this->set(compact('nominationInfor','userNumber','award_id'));

        if($this->request->isAjax()){

            $this->render('load_comments','ajax');
        }

    }
}
```

Load_comments, being the view thus being called, has an Ajax button which has the view code shown below:

```
echo $this->Js->submit('Demote Comment',array(

                'url'=>array(
                    'controller'=>'AwardNominees',
                    'action'=>'load_comments'
                    ),
                'before'=>$this->Js->get('#demot')->effect('fadeIn'),
                'success'=>$this->Js->get('#demot')->effect('fadeOut'),
                'update'=>'#comments'
                ));

            echo $this->Form->end();
```

When the Demote Comment button is clicked,

```
debug($this->request->isAjax());
```

returns false, but if LOAD COMMENTS is clicked

```
debug($this->request->isAjax());
```

returns true. The idea is when Load Comments is clicked, the comments are loaded then when Demote Comment is clicked(which is the button against a comment) i wanted to make an Ajax call removing the comment thereof. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you forgot to add `echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();` at the end of your view

Comment: Why RequestHandler? It will depreciate on future...

Comment: try to use `$this->request->isAjax();` And update your question with full controller code?? Its hard to understand what going on with this little code..

Comment: @FazalRasel i have added the full controller action code and have removed RequestHandler. Hopefully its clearer now.I have    echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(); in my default layout.

Comment: You should echo `$this->Js->writeBuffer();` also in all Ajax rendered views.

Comment: @noslone I have tried it but it seems it doesnt solve my problem.

Comment: Are you using Prototype or jQuery? When using Prototype you will also need to provide `'evalScripts' => true` for all Ajax links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out where i was going wrong with reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033070/2-ajax-calls-in-the-same-view-cakephp-2-3)

On my submit buttons i added 'buffer'=>false in the array with my callback functions thus the final submit is as shown below

```
                echo $this->Js->submit('Demote Comment',array(
                    'url'=>array(
                    'controller'=>'AwardNominees',
                    'action'=>'load_comments'
                    ),
                'before'=>$this->Js->get('#demot')->effect('fadeIn'),
                'success'=>$this->Js->get('#demot')->effect('fadeOut'),
                'update'=>'#comments',
                'buffer' => false
                ));
```

and i put different id to the forms that i created. This got my code working as expected. :-)